# Ios can no longer submit app to ituens getting ".....is not signed using an apple submission certificate

Tags: ios

My app sub was working, now I'm getting the following error
"the bundle 'tele' at bundle path "cardreading.app" is not signed using an apple submission certificate"

Is was working.  I tried googoling the error, came up empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check (In XCode) which build configuration you are using when archiving the application (Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme->Archive). Now open your build settings for the target and confirm that, for this build configuration, you are using the proper app submission certificate (search for "code signing" in your build settings)